# How to track refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

I hava some view state om my page  and when someome click refresh button or f5 I would like  my view state to be saved.
So  are any ways to track pressing f5 or refresh button on browser via javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You may get help from

```
https://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide
```

or you can use Google Analytics

```
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#what_data_does_the_tracking_snippet_capture
```